# Fixing Integrity Error in Python

Tags: python, mysql

When you're trying to debug a program in python that pulls from a few other databases/folders. After looking up what the integrity error means, how do you find out where it is happening exactly? Is there a command you can insert into the code that will print out where that error is happening? A try/except clause maybe?

Examples of errors I ran into:

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1364, "Field 'id' doesn't have a default value")

sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (_mysql_exceptions.IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hbnb_dev_db`.`cities`, CONSTRAINT `cities_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`state_id`) REFERENCES `states` (`id`))')

Answer (score 0):

Your issues are not python, they are simple SQL errors:

- The first error indicates that you are trying to make an `insert` statement and you are missing the column `id` from the insert statement.
- The second indicates that you are trying to update a key in a table but that column is referenced by another field in another table.

To help you better in the future, include your code that is generating the error and put each problem is a separate post